# How do I tag Facebook friends in a post

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Now it is know that we can not post on multiple friend's wall after Feb 2013, the other way around that I can think of notifying all friends or selected friends is tagging in some status update or post. It seems that it not possible too. Is there any other way that I can achieve the same gole of notifying multiple users with **Facebook sdk 3.5 for iOS**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this if you use the Open Graph to tell stories. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/#people

Otherwise, if you're simply posting to me/feed you cannot tag or mention users.